# Find probability of getting $k$ magenta balls

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In box we have $1$ magenta and $1$ white ball. We realize $n$ times the given algorithm:

- Random take $1$ ball from box
- Return to box taken ball and $1$ more with exactly the same color

Find the probability that at the end we will have $k$ magenta balls.

### My try

The hint was to use induction. So I wrote the decision tree for that problem.

$$n=0: MW $$
$$n=1: MMW \;\;\; MWW $$
$$n=2: MMMW \;\;\; MMWW \;\;\; MMWW \;\;\; MWWW $$

Let $P(M_{n,k})$ will be probability of getting $k$ magentas after $n$ steps. We see that
$P(M_{2,3}) = 1/4, P(M_{2,2}) = 1/2 P(M_{2,1}) = 1/4 $ 
 and 
$P(M_{1,1}) = 1/2, P(M_{1,2}) = 1/2$ 
I don't see a pattern there, the more steps will be printed, the more different values there will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seemingly, you assumed that each transition in the tree happens with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, which is incorrect.
Indeed, $P(M_{1,1})=P(M_{1,2})=\frac{1}{2}$, but we have that $$P(M_{2,3})=\frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{3}=\frac{1}{3}, P(M_{2,1}) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{3}=\frac{1}{3}, P(M_{2,2})=1-P(M_{2,1})-P(M_{2,3}) = \frac{1}{3}$$
So we got that $P(M_{2,i})=\frac{1}{3}$ for each $i\in[3]$.
Now do you see a pattern?

Comment: Why do you have $ \frac23\ $ in $ P(M_{2,3})=\frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{3}=\frac{1}{3}$ ?

Comment: After you took a magenta ball in step $1$, you have $2$ magenta balls out of $3$ total balls, so the probability that magenta will be picked again is now $\frac{2}{3}$

Comment: Great, now I see a pattern. Thanks

Comment: If we change the algorithm slightly, instead of putting 1 more ball of same color, we put ball of the remaining color. Will a pattern still emerge?